# Round table seating - expected value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $p$ women, $s$ men and $p+s$ seats in a round table. Let $X$ be the number of women who sit between two men. Find the expected value of $X$.

I know that expected value of $X$ is given by the formula: $EX=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n)$, because X is a discrete random variable with non-negative integer values, but I don't know what to do next.

For any given women: $P(X_i=1)= {\binom{s}{2}2!(p-1+s-2)!\over (p-1+s)!}$ . I choose two men $\binom{s}{2}$, change their sides $2!$ and permute the rest of people $(p-1+s-2)!$ . Is it correct now?

Comment: "I don't know what to do next." Forget this formula and rather ask yourself: *what is the probability that any given woman is seated between two men?*

Answer (score 2):

Your probability for a given woman to sit between two men is correct. You could derive it more easily by considering only her two neighbours: Select one neighbour; with probability $\frac s{p+s-1}$ it's a man; and then select the other neigbour; with probability $\frac{s-1}{p+s-2}$ it's another man. Now by linearity of expectation you can just multiply the resulting probability by the number of women to obtain the expected number of women sitting between two men,

$$
p\cdot\frac{s(s-1)}{(p+s-1)(p+s-2)}\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

denote $X_i=1_{\{the\ i-th\ women\ is\ between\ two\ men\}}$. Then $$X=\sum_{i=1}^p X_i,$$ and so, $$EX=\sum_{i=1}^p EX_i.$$ We have that $E[X_i]=p\{X_i=1\}$. Moreover, $p\{X_i=1\}=\frac{s}{p+s}$, then $$EX=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{s}{p+s}=\frac{ps}{p+s}.$$

Comment: Wrong (and unmotivated) value of $P(X_i=1)$.